# Get status code returned with PhantomJS using a bridge

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I am creating a small API to monitor the perfomance of some of my sites. For that I want the loadtime, and the http status code. I am using node js and phatomjs to do this, and so far I have the loadtime just right, but I can't seem to get the status code back. I've tried some different things, but none are working so far.

This is my code now:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.type('application/json');
        res.send('{"status": "running"}');
});

app.get('/site/:url', function(req, res){
        res.type('application/json');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
        var url = decodeURIComponent(req.param('url'));
        var phantom = require('phantom');
        var time, code;

        phantom.create(function(ph){
                ph.createPage(function(page){
                        time = Date.now();
                        page.open(url, function(status){
                                time = Date.now() - time;

                                res.send({"status": status, "time": time});
                        });
                });
        });
});

var server = app.listen(80, function() {
        var host = server.address().address;
        var port = server.address().port;

        console.log('Got\'cha .. ', host, port);
});
```

I've tried http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-received.html but I can't seem to see where I can call it so I can return it together with my other data. So far I am getting something like this `{"status":"success","time":1723}`.

Does someone have an idea of what I could do?

Comment: I've tried http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-received.html but I can't seem to see where I can call it so I can return it together with my other data. So far I am getting something like this `{"status":"success","time":1723}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that [`onResourceReceived`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-received.html) provides the actual status code. As shown in the [functionality details](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node#functionality-details), you have to set the event handlers with `page.set`.

You can assume that `onResourceReceived` is executed before the page `open` callback:

```
var statusCode = null;
page.set('onResourceReceived', function(resource){
    statusCode = resource.status;
});
page.open(url, function(status){
    time = Date.now() - time;
    res.send({"status": statusCode, "time": time});
});
```

If you can't be certain (you should do some tests), then you can use something like `waitFor` [from here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js):

```
var statusCode = null;
page.set('onResourceReceived', function(resource){
    statusCode = resource.status;
});
page.open(url, function(status){
    waitFor(function(){
        return !!statusCode;
    }, function(){
        time = Date.now() - time;
        res.send({"status": statusCode, "time": time});
    });
});
```